# Animating nebular sidebar component

Tags: css, angular, nebular

I am using nebular sidebar component, what i'm trying to do is animating the opening and the closing of the sidebar.
I checked the sidebar API but i didn't find anything that can do that ? I tried to apply css transition on the class but it didn't work, so how can i approach this ?

```
<nb-layout>

  <nb-layout-header subheader>
    <app-navbar style="width: 100%"></app-navbar>
  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar [state]="'compacted'">
    <app-sidenav-menu></app-sidenav-menu>
  </nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Comment: Hey, Ali Badr, please check answer from Nikita as correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I see it, the Nebular sidebar contains container inside:

```
<nb-sidebar>
  <div.main-container>
  ...
  </div>
</nb-sidebar>
```

And if you add transitions for both, `sidebar` and `div.main-container` it should provide the desired behavior.

```
nb-sidebar,
nb-sidebar > div.main-container {
  transition: width 1s;
}
```